# Trying to insert a node into a linked list but I need an overload operator< function

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, derived-class, base-class

I have a main function that works with a linked list and two classes: One base(BankAcct) and one derived (CheckAcct). I need help with writing an overload operator< function.

This is part of main:

```
LinkedList<CheckAcct> list;

// Add acounts
vector<string> v = { "Bill Gates", "Melinda Gates" };   // vector with 2 owners
CheckAcct acct1(v, 5000, 1234);  // input args: owners, amount, acct number
// 1. add acct1 to the list:
list.insertNode(acct1);
```

And this is the insert function in the linked list file:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
struct ListNode
{
  T data ;
  struct ListNode * next;
};

ListNode *head;

public:
LinkedList() { head = nullptr; }
 ~LinkedList();

// Linked list operations
void insertNode(T);
bool deleteNode(T);
void displayList() const;
};

// insertNode: add a node in list order
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertNode(T newValue)
{
ListNode *newNode;
ListNode *pCur;
ListNode *pPre = NULL;

newNode = new ListNode;
newNode->data = newValue;
newNode->next = nullptr;

if (head == nullptr)
{
  head = newNode;
}
else
{
    pCur = head;
    pPre = nullptr;
    while (pCur != nullptr && pCur->data < newValue)
    {
        pPre = pCur;
        pCur = pCur->next;
    }

    if (pPre == nullptr)
    {
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = pCur;
    }
    else
    {
        pPre->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = pCur;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Since only you apprently knows what the classes the template functions will be used with, and how the < operator should work for them, the only one who could possibly answer this question would also be you. Unclear what's being asked here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the template is a CheckAcct object and the objects are inserted and sorted by the account number (the third input argument). I have several CheckAcct objects to insert but I am showing only one in main right now.

Comment: Well, that sounds to me like you have everything that's needed to overload the < operator. Nothing to do here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik this is the error that I get when I run the program: error: no match for 'operator<' in 'pCur->LinkedList<CheckAcct>::ListNode::data < newValue

Comment: Well, then, define and implement the operator.

Answer (score 0):

Here are operator details (including '<'): [Click here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)